# Why Hikari construct a bad database url?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-sql, hikaricp

I have problem using HikariCP and Google App Engine for JEE.

When trying to access site, i have the logged error :

`com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Cannot connect to MySQL server on localhost:3,306.`

As you can see, it add a ',' in the port address.

I try to send full URL to it but nothing append. 
Here is my Servlet INIT class :

```
public class InitialServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static final String SEANCE_MANAGER = "SEANCE_MANAGER";

    public static final String CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME="";
    public static final String DB_USER="test_db";
    public static final String DB_PASS="password";
    public static final String DB_NAME="dbname";

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        HikariConfig configs = new HikariConfig();

        configs.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname");
        configs.setUsername(DB_USER);
        configs.setPassword(DB_PASS); 


        configs.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory");
        configs.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME);
        configs.addDataSourceProperty("useSSL", "false");


        DataSource pool = new HikariDataSource(configs);

        DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess(pool);

        SeancesManager seancesManager = new SeancesManager(dataAccess);
        config.getServletContext().setAttribute(SEANCE_MANAGER, seancesManager);

    }
}
```

How i can do to fix this bug ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only difference from the official connection specified in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#connecting_to) that you can follow in order to connect App Engine with Cloud SQL through Java that I see is the format of the setJdbcurl.

I know this might be far fetched but can you attempt to format the setJdbcUrl like this?

```
config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql:///%s", DB_NAME));
```

Also please double check the connection variables in case something went through.

Let me know and if it doesn't work we will look more into it.

EDIT:

Are you using [SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)?

If you are using SQL Proxy run the command again and make sure you specify the port correctly.

That is the first thing that I can think off where you can specify the port and maybe had a "," in the command you specified.

Another thing I wonder, are you overwriting or have you modified the port number in any place? I would recommend you checking that because the error "3,306" is because the port specified is "3,306". The normal failure error directly fails with 3306.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, 
I just try to do this way and, the same error is logged. 
I really don't know how to set this value manually .

Comment: What do you mean by "don't know how to set this value manually"? I'm not understanding what are you finding problems with. Did you check that the variables are correct? Is the Cloud SQL connection name in the correct format?

What are you using Cloud SDK, Cloud Shell or using a plugin for JEE?

Comment: I see that there is no problem with the address. Don't know why it can't connect to localhost. I try to ping localhost on port in shell and it receive it perfectly...